# Do StarCraft 2 Guest Passes affect my World of Warcraft account?

Tags: starcraft-2, world-of-warcraft

I have two Guest Passes for World of Warcraft, and two for StarCraft 2. If my friend makes a StarCraft 2 account off of the Guest Pass, does my WoW account get a mount? I do not have a StarCraft 2 account.

Answer (score 6):

No

The only way I know of to get a mount from inviting other players to play is through World of Warcraft's [Recruit a Friend](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/services/recruit-a-friend/) service.  You have to go through Recruit a Friend (which involves playing WoW) and your friend has to pay for a couple months in order to get the mount.

Those guest passes don't do anything for *you*, really; they just let your friend play for free for a while. Even if you did have StarCraft II, you wouldn't get anything tangible out of your friend using your Guest Passes (other than being able to play with your friend, of course).

Comment: And you don't even get the mount until 2 months AFTER the 15 day trial period! Assuming your friend pays for 2 months.

Comment: @Tristan. You get the mount after your friend has *paid* for two months, he could do that instantly, like if he uses a gamecard, or buys a 3 or 6 month subscription.

Comment: Also, for clarity, note that currently, having a friend playing SC2 cannot not affect your WoW account at all. There are no bonuses in that regard.